Trying to create full-duplex tcp server
I am trying to create full duplex server, I have implemented this rust code but it is not working, so what could be modification need to be done to make it works.
What is best practice to implement this?
This is client file, which connect to server but it does not send or receive data. When server quite, it goes into infinite loop?
client.rs
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::thread;

static mut FLAG: bool = false;

fn send_to_server(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    unsafe {
        while !FLAG {
            let mut send_msg = String::new();
            if let Ok(_) = io::stdin().read_line(&mut send_msg) {
                stream
                    .write_all(send_msg.as_bytes())
                    .expect("Failed to send message to server");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn recv_from_server(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    unsafe {
        loop {
            let mut data = String::new();
            if let Ok(_) = stream.read_to_string(&mut data) {
                if data.trim() == "quit" {
                    println!("Closing connection");
                    FLAG = true;
                    break;
                }
                println!("Server: {}", data);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut threads = vec![];

    let host = "localhost";
    let port = 6500;

    if let Ok(mut client_socket) = TcpStream::connect(format!("{}:{}", host, port)) {
        println!("Client is connected to the Server");

        if let Ok(send_socket) = client_socket.try_clone() {
            let t_send = thread::spawn(move || send_to_server(send_socket));
            threads.push(t_send);
        }

        let recv_socket = client_socket;
        let t_rcv = thread::spawn(move || recv_from_server(recv_socket));
        threads.push(t_rcv);

        for thread in threads {
            thread.join().expect("Thread panicked");
        }
    } else {
        eprintln!("Failed to connect to server");
    }

    println!("EXITING");
}


This is server file, which connect to client but not able to receive and send data.
server.rs
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;

static mut FLAG: bool = false;

fn recv_from_client(mut conn: TcpStream) {
    unsafe {
        loop {
            if FLAG {
                break;
            }
            let mut message = String::new();
            if let Ok(_) = conn.read_to_string(&mut message) {
                if message.trim() == "quit" {
                    conn.write_all(b"quit")
                        .expect("Failed to send 'quit' message");
                    conn.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Both)
                        .expect("Failed to shutdown connection");
                    println!("Connection Closed");
                    FLAG = true;
                    break;
                }
                println!("Client: {}", message);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn send_to_client(mut conn: TcpStream) {
    unsafe {
        loop {
            if FLAG {
                break;
            }
            let mut send_msg = String::new();
            if let Ok(_) = io::stdin().read_line(&mut send_msg) {
                if send_msg.trim() == "quit" {
                    conn.write_all(b"quit")
                        .expect("Failed to send 'quit' message");
                    conn.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Both)
                        .expect("Failed to shutdown connection");
                    println!("Connection Closed");
                    FLAG = true;
                    break;
                }
                conn.write_all(send_msg.as_bytes())
                    .expect("Failed to send message to client");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut threads = vec![];

    let host = "localhost";
    let server_port = 6500;

    if let Ok(server_socket) = TcpListener::bind(format!("{}:{}", host, server_port)) {
        println!("Socket binded.");

        println!("Listening.....");
        if let Ok((connection_socket, addr)) = server_socket.accept() {
            println!("Connection Established with a Client on {}", addr);

            if let Ok(recv_socket) = connection_socket.try_clone() {
                let t_rcv = thread::spawn(move || recv_from_client(recv_socket));
                threads.push(t_rcv);
            }

            if let Ok(send_socket) = connection_socket.try_clone() {
                let t_send = thread::spawn(move || send_to_client(send_socket));
                threads.push(t_send);
            }
        } else {
            eprintln!("Failed to establish connection with client");
            return;
        }

        for thread in threads {
            thread.join().expect("Thread panicked");
        }

        println!("EXITING");
    } else {
        eprintln!("Failed to bind socket");
    }
}



Do not ever use static mut.

You have a data race (UB).

"it's not working" please add technical details how, (doesn't compile, panics,...)
